# Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up in macOS

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to run my first react native application for android(created using react native cli) in macOS, but I am getting the following error every time.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file '/Users/avinash/Personal/React-Native/AwesomeProject/android/settings.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile settings file '/Users/avinash/Personal/React-Native/AwesomeProject/android/settings.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 60
  
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60
```

```
BUILD FAILED in 5s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file '/Users/avinash/Personal/React-Native/AwesomeProject/android/settings.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile settings file '/Users/avinash/Personal/React-Native/AwesomeProject/android/settings.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 60
  
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60
```

My system java configuration is

```
$ javac -version 
javac 16.0.1
```

```
$ java --version
java 16.0.1 2021-04-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.1+9-24)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.1+9-24, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: could you have a look at your JDK version and update?

Comment: $ javac -version
javac 16.0.1

Comment: $ java --version
java 16.0.1 2021-04-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.1+9-24)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.1+9-24, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: I think it is related to the JDK version 16, can you downgrade it to 11 and try again?

Comment: Just FYI, if you are a beginner I'd recommend using expo instead of react-natlive-cli, that way you don't have to worry about your environment at all.

Comment: @Krismu I am new to react-native-cli, I was using expo earlier but facing lots of issue with analytics plugin to moving to react-native-cli

Comment: @nithinpp It's working fine after downgrading to java 11

Comment: Cool. { happy coding }